# MS09-035 Vulnerability & Impact On Application Development

Tags: .net, visual-studio, security, atl

Does anyone know if these patches http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms09-035.mspx and http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms09-034.mspx will apply to software built using one of the 'pure' (ie. not managed C++) .NET languages?

I believe the answer is that they are unaffected as this seems to be a pure ATL vulnerability, but don't have enough knowledge in the underlying usage of ATL in the CLR to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the *Affected and Non-Affected Software* section, Visual Studio 2003, 2005, 2008 are listed, but the .NET frameworks are not listed.

There's a section on the page that provides developer details: [Active Template Library Security Update for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee309358.aspx) and that article is explicitly targetted at Visual C++ developers and makes no mention of the .NET framework.

So given the above lack of mention of .NET framework: **No News is Good News**!

You can also follow this diagram to determine if you're vulnerable:

[image: ATL vulnerability check]

Comment: For some reason, that tree doesn't display correctly unless you've already visited that article page where it appears. I've copied to my hosting and fixed the link so it displays correctly here now.

Comment: Snap - Thanks for catching that... and then fixing it!

Comment: Thanks - I'd seen the diagram, but wanted a second opinion :)